# Show that all level sets of the Hamiltonian are bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

Consider the system
$$
\dot{x}=y,~~~~~~~~~~\dot{y}=x^2-x^3.
$$
Its Hamiltonian is
$$
H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}.
$$

> > Show that all level sets of the Hamiltonian are bounded.

As far as I see, it is meant to show that the set
$$
\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: H(x,y)=c\right\}
$$
is a bounded set.

My computation gives that $H(x,y)=c\Leftrightarrow y=\sqrt{2c+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^4}$, i.e.
$$
\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: H(x,y)=c\right\}=\left\{(x,y): y=\sqrt{2c+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^4}\right\}
$$

How can I see that this is a bounded set?

Comment: Two small (and completely unrelated) notes: 1. Taking the square root "loses half of the solutions". 2. The \TeX commands `\quad` and `\qquad` give one or two ems of horizontal space, obviating `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`-type hacks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could think about different ways to show this, and after a while we might think that it would be nice to show that any level set of $H$ is contained within some ellipse. That would definitely mean that any level set is bounded.

In formulas, this would mean showing that any $x,y$-pair satisfying

$$
\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4} = c
$$

satisfies

$$
ay^2 + bx^2 \leq d
$$

for some $a,b,d > 0$ which depend on $c$. The first equation already has a $y^2$ term, so we might be able to get away with $a=1/2$. For now let's also take the simplest choice for $b$, namely $b=1$, and hope this doesn't complicate finding $d$.

So now we want to show that if $(x,y)$ satisfies

$$
\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4} = c \tag{1}
$$

then

$$
\frac{y^2}{2} + x^2 \leq d \tag{2}
$$

for some $d$ depending on $c$.

With our target $(2)$ in mind, let's rearrange $(1)$ like

$$
\frac{y^2}{2} + x^2 = -\frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^3}{3} + x^2 + c = p(x) + c. \tag{3}
$$

The polynomial $p(x) = - x^4/4 + x^3/3 + x^2$ is bounded above, and to find this bound we first calculate

$$
p'(x) = -x^3 + x^2 + 2x = -x(x+1)(x-2),
$$

and then check that $p(0) = 0$, $p(-1) = 5/12$, and $p(2) = 8/3$ to conclude that $p(x) \leq 8/3$, and hence, from $(3)$, we conclude that if

$$
\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4} = c
$$

then

$$
\frac{y^2}{2} + x^2 \leq c + \frac{8}{3},
$$

which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{2c+\frac 23 x^3- \frac 12 x^4}$ The domain of existence of $f$ is

$$\mathcal D:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 2c+\frac 23 x^3- \frac 12 x^4\geq 0\}$$

You should notice that asymptotics tell us that there exists a certain $x_0$ such that 
 $$|\frac 12 x^4| > |2c+\frac 23 x^3|~~~~~~ \textrm{for} ~x>x_0$$
You can actually prove this through explicitly solving the inequality, although I would not recommend it, calculations get messy. This implies that for $|x|>x_0$ the argument of the square root becomes negative.

Since the domain is the preimage of the set $[0, +\infty[$ which is closed and $f$ is continuous, $\mathcal{D} $ is closed. We have previously shown that it is bounded by $B(0, x_0+\varepsilon]$. You could get better bounds, but this is enough for what we're concerned. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is closed and bounded, it is compact.

Since $f$ is continuous on its  compact domain, it attains a maximum and a minimum value for Weierstrass' theorem; Since both domain and codomain are bounded, the graph of this function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is too.

Comment: Why the downvote?